# Erro "No match for operator <<" em C++

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++, c++14, c++-builder

Eu fiz esse codigo porém não faço a minima ideia porque esta dando esse erro : "No match for 'operator <<' Na parte em que exibo a resposta do usuário... (Lembrando que NomePessoa é uma classe e a Data tambem...)

```
class Filme
   {
   private:
    string titulo;
    NomePessoa Diretor;
    NomePessoa Personagem;
    Data Lancamento;

   public:

     void getInfo(string t, string d, string p, int dia, int m, int a)
        {
            titulo = t;
            Diretor.Grava(d);
            Personagem.Grava(p);
            Lancamento.getData(dia,m,a);
        };

    void imprime()
        {
            cout << "Titulo: " << titulo << endl ;
            cout << "Nome do Diretor: " << Diretor.Imprime() << endl;
            cout << "Nome do Personagem Principal: " << Personagem.Imprime() << endl;
            cout << "Data do Lançamento: " << Lancamento.sendData() << endl;
        };
```

Comment: Você provavelmente precisa implementar o operador `<<` nas classes `NomePessoa` e `Data`, porque elas não devem saber o que fazer quando o operador `<<` é usado, veja aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22588202/8133067

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro significa que o compilador não sabe como escrever o objeto `File` na stream indicada. Isso acontece porque algures tem no seu código tem algo como:

```
Filme f;
cout << f;
```

Como não implementou o operador `<<` para `Filme` o compilador não consegue resolver essa instrução, pois não sabe como escrever um `Filme` no `cout`.

No entanto você já tem o código que mostra um `Filme` no método `imprime` e por isso basta implementar o operador `<<` utilizando essa lógica já feita:

```
class Filme
{
   private:
    //...

   public:

     void getInfo(string t, string d, string p, int dia, int m, int a)
     {
         titulo = t;
         Diretor.Grava(d);
         Personagem.Grava(p);
         Lancamento.getData(dia,m,a);
     };

     //aqui implementação do operador <<
     friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Filme& f)
     {
         //O acesso ao Filme é feito pelo segundo parametro que chamei de f
         os << "Titulo: " << f.titulo << endl ;
         os << "Nome do Diretor: " << f.Diretor.Imprime() << endl;
         os << "Nome do Personagem Principal: " << f.Personagem.Imprime() << endl;
         os << "Data do Lançamento: " << f.Lancamento.sendData() << endl;
         return os ;
     }
```